# sails.js-hook-scheddule - how to specify cron timing string

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How can i specify the timings for scheduling a task in sails-hook-schedule? I got this basic example from their docs.

```
module.exports.schedule = {
  sailsInContext : true, //If sails is not as global and you want to have it in your task
  tasks : {
      //Every monday at 1am
      firstTask : {
         cron : "0 1 * * 1",
         task : function (context, sails)
         {
              console.log("cron ok");
         },
         context : {}
      }
  }
};
```

Now what does this line means?

```
cron : "0 1 * * 1",
```

What i understood is that this is how i specify the timings for the schedule. I wanted to run a specific task at every 12 am in the morning. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string is a cron expression. [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) allows the users to schedule jobs to run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals in Unix-like computer OS.

You can find plenty of tutorials online to learn how to write one.

You've also got helpers [to translate a cron expression in plain english](https://crontab.guru/#0_1_*_*_1), or [to generate a cron expression](http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html).

The one you gave run the `task` method on mondays at 1 am.

If you want to schedule it to run at 12 am on each morning, you can use this cron expression: [`0 0 * * *`](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_*).

Comment: Thank you very much, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link - [Cron Tab Guru](https://crontab.guru/) to find out what the cron expression mean. It gives you the description of the cron expression. I find it very useful.

Comment: Thanks mate, @Yann Bertrand also answered with the same link